# How to concatenate over 2 ndarray in loop(one of these is empty in 1st loop)?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to achieve this function in Python like Matlab

in matlab, the code is (B and C are variables in loop)

```
A = [];
for ii = 1:10
    A = [A, B, C]
end
```

but in Python, use np.hstack or np.concatenate, the ndarray must have same number of dimensions

and, that is my Python code

```
for ii in range(10):
    if ii == 0:
        A = np.hstack([B, C])
    else:
        A = np.hstack([A, B, C])
```

but, i think it a little troublesome and unreadable.

how can i rewrite it?(It's better to use only one line of code)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: What is your actual input?

Comment: Short answer, `np.hstack` once and then `np.tile`. Even in MATLAB, your loop is not a recommended approach.

Comment: why close my question？B and C is variable not constant，NOT REPEAT NDARRAY！

Comment: We recommend setting `alist=[]`, and doing `alist.append(B)` in the loop.  Then do **one** `np.hstack(alist)` at the end.  List append is much more efficient because it just adds a reference in-place.  Repeated `hstack` is slower because it makes a new array (with full copy) each time.

Comment: The duplicate isn't the best, but you code example does not adequately convey the variability that you want us to use.  Like I wrote above, list append is the way to go.